# Does every validly posed Sudoku have at least one solution and if not what is the minimum number of givens for it to be unsolvable?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, optimization, sudoku, solvability

Does every validly posed Sudoku (doesn't break any Sudoku rules so only no duplicate 1 to 9 in rows, columns or square) have at least one solution, and if not, what is the minimum number of givens for it to be unsolvable?

According to Wikipedia:

> The puzzle setter provides a partially completed grid, which for a **well-posed puzzle** has a single solution.

Many others sources including Sudopedia do not state that a Sudoku-like grid with given 1 to 9 numbers has to have one solution to be a Sudoku.

Does have given numbers mean it is solvable, and assuming no, what is the least numbers in a validly posed grid needed to be for it be unsolvable?

Comment: "Unsolvable" in the sense of having no completions?

Comment: "Well-posed" there means "well-designed", not "valid at first glance"

Comment: A "validly posed grid" as in "you must make at least one deduction to know there can be no solution"?

Answer (score 3):

5 numbers are certainly enough to make it unsolvable.
This is a simple example :
[image: grid created with sudoku9x9.com]

You can never put one in the bottom left corner.
Maybe someone has an optimization?